# Location of the table space files?

Tags: oracle, tablespace

How can I find the directory in which oracle stores it's table space files?

When I do: `select * from dba_data_files;` or `select * from v$datafile;` then I get some paths like that:

```
+DATA01/fu/datafile/bar_ts01_data.260.264360912
```

But what means `+DATA01`? And where is that exactly in the file system?

Comment: path of asm data directory

Answer (score 7, accepted):

+DATA01/fu/datafile/bar_ts01_data.260.264360912

Yes this is correct file path. It means you use ASM disk.

After you login to OS with "grid" user [usually Oracle Grid Infrastructure installation user is named like that], run following command to browse files on ASM disk.

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/11.2.0/grid --this is also usual installation dir, may differ on your case
export ORACLE_SID=+ASM
cd $ORACLE_HOME/bin
./asmcmd -p
ASMCMD>ls
+DATA01
+DATA02
ASMCMD>cd +DATA01
```

Answer (score 2):

In that table, the `file_name` field should give the full path to the datafile.

Also, try `select * from v$datafile;` and that view should help as well.

Comment: `select * from v$datafile;` returns the same paths like my query. I updated my question.

Comment: Please note it ```name``` not ```file_name``` so it  ```select name from v$datafile;```